# Cannot find function `jsx:is_json/1` although jsx is included and compiled

Tags: functional-programming, erlang, rebar3

I am writing a webapp using Erlang toolchain (OTP, rebar3, cowboy, jsx...). The following code does not work because `jsx:is_json/1` cannot be found during runtime.

```
handle_login(Req, State) ->
  {ok, Data, _} = cowboy_req:body(Req),

  case jsx:is_json(Data) of
    false -> cowboy_req:reply(400,
      [
        {<<"content-type">>, <<"application/json">>}
      ],
      <<"Invalid JSON">>,
      Req);
```

Stacktrace:

```
{[{reason,undef},
   {mfa,{erbid_api_handler,handle,2}},
   {stacktrace,
      [{jsx,is_json,[<<"{\"username\":\"tom\"}">>],[]},
       {erbid_api_handler,handle_login,2,
           [{file,
                "/Users/khanhhua/dev/project-erbid/_build/default/lib/erbid/src/erbid_api_handler.erl"},
            {line,45}]},
       {erbid_api_handler,handle,2,
... truncated for brevity
```

Folder structure:
[image: Project's _build folder structure]

I need to know how to fix the issue. Thanks.

Comment: What rebar3 command are you running to start your application?

Comment: @Stratus3D Thanks for your comment. It's `_build/default/rel/erbid_alpha/bin/erbid_alpha foreground`. Anways, I have fixed the silly issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the cause of this issue. I did not not include module `jsx` in my `erbid.app.src`'s applications section.

```
{application, erbid, [
    {description, "Realtime system"},
    {vsn, "0.1.0"},
    {registered, []},
    {applications, [
        kernel,
        stdlib,
        cowboy,
        jsx
    ]},
    {mod, {erbid, []}},
    {env, []}
]}.
```

Totally due to my lack of Erlang experience.